# PythonAnywhere. Асинхронность OpenAi. Ошибка SSL. Telegram-bot

Tags: telegram-bot, многопоточность, асинхронность, pythonanywhere, openapi

Сегодня я решил сменить последовательное выполнение запросов OpenAi на асинхронное:

```
# Функция для последовательного вызова OpenAI
async def call_openai(message) -> str:
    global user_message
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    # Или какой-то другой способ получения сообщения от пользователя
    user_messages[user_id].append({"role": "user", "content": user_message})

    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
        messages=user_messages[user_id],
        temperature=0.8,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0.3,
        max_tokens=max_token_count,
    )

    response_content = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    return response_content, response
```

На это:

```
# Функция для асинхронного вызова OpenAI
async def call_openai(message) -> str:
    global user_message
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    # Или какой-то другой способ получения сообщения от пользователя
    user_messages[user_id].append({"role": "user", "content": user_message})

    response = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
        messages=user_messages[user_id],
        temperature=0.8,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0.3,
        max_tokens=max_token_count,
    )

    response_content = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    return response_content, response
```

И в обычном Pycharm всё работает идеально, но на сервисе по деплою - PythonAnywhere - возникла ошибка коммуникации с API OpenAi, как только я сменил

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create
```

на

```
response = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate
```

Возможно, проблема заключается в том, что я использую PROXY_URL, который не пропускает OpenAI или сам PythonAnywhere, но без него он выдаёт другую ошибку о незащищённом соединении.

```
PROXY_URL = "http://proxy.server:3128"
bot = Bot(token=telegram_token, proxy=PROXY_URL)
```

Вот текст ошибки:

```
*Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /home/svkl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:407> exception=TypeError("'coroutine' object is not subscriptable")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/svkl/main.py", line 273, in handle_messages
    response_content, response = await call_openai(message)
  File "/home/svkl/main.py", line 324, in call_openai
/home/svkl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/datalib/numpy_helper.py:4: UserWarning: The NumPy module was reloaded (imported a second time). This can in some cases result in small but subtle issues and is discouraged.
  import numpy
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-335' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /home/svkl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:407> exception=APIConnectionError(message='Error communicating with OpenAI', http_status=None, request_id=None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/svkl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 535, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('104.18.7.192', 443)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.openai.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('104.18.7.192', 443)]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    raise error.APIConnectionError("Error communicating with OpenAI") from e
openai.error.APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI*
```